# Why is my NetworkStream.Write() slow when writing back received data to browser?

Tags: vb.net

I am building a simple proxy in  server vb.NET and so far it has been successful, but then whenever i receive data from the internet and write it back to my browser's network stream using `NetworkStream.Write` the received data tends to come up slowly to my browser due to reasons i do not know of. But when I chain my application to another Proxy/listener on my local computer (e.g Privoxy), data seems to come up very fast to my browser. If anyone has an answer to this I would really love to know. Thanks

btw here is the part of my code {subroutine} that receives data and forwards to my browser.

```
 Public Sub ForwardRequest(ByVal Client As TcpClient, ByVal ClientMessage As String)

        Dim Browser As TcpClient = Client
        Dim BrowserStream As NetworkStream = Browser.GetStream
        Dim Server As TcpClient = New TcpClient(IPAddress.Parse("testwebsite.com").ToString, 80)
        Dim ServerStream As NetworkStream = Server.GetStream

        ServerStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ClientMessage), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ClientMessage).Length)

        Dim Buffer(1024) As Byte
        Dim ReceivedInt As Integer

        Do
            ReceivedInt = ServerStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
            BrowserStream.Write(Buffer, 0, ReceivedInt)
        Loop While (ReceivedInt > 0)

        BrowserStream.Flush() 'I read somewhere that this does nothing though
        BrowserStream.Close()
        Browser.Close()
        ServerStream.Close()
        Server.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: I marked up your code as a code block, so it formatted better. I also corrected `Lenght` to `Length`, which means this *isn't* your code, but made up code, so it may not exhibit the same problems as your real code.

Comment: You've also not shown any kind of looping, to deal with responses > 1024 bytes in length, which I assume your real code does have. Are you overlapping your reads and writes, or does your code only do one or the other at any time? It's difficult to diagnose when we're not seeing the real code (and/or not enough of it to see what you're actually doing)

Comment: I've put in the whole code, is there anything i'm missing and why my write is slow?

Comment: Answers? Anyone? cos this is such a mystery to me :(

Comment: so far I haven't been able to figure out the cause for this, I've tried using `Sockets` as against `TcpClient` but I still get the same delay, if anyone has managed to figure this mystery out, i would be glad to hear it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve the "mystery" myself, I went ahead to use `Asynchronous Sockets` socket and everything started working great.
Thanks.